# how stop resubmission of data into the database when the action page is refreshed

Tags: jsp

I am having a problem with my jsp project. when ever i submit my form ,data is inserted into the database and a an auto generated userid and password is shown to the user. but when i click refresh button the same data is resubmitted with a new userid and password. 
code for the form and insertion  is below .

**stinsrt.jsp**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>STUDENT REGISTRATION</title>
         <%@ include file="connect.jsp" %>
         <script>
    window.history.forward();
    </script>
    <script language="javascript">

</script>


    </head>
            <center><img border="0" src="Student Info Systems.jpg" alt="Pulpit rock" width="304" height="228" /></center>
    <body>
        <%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.* , java.io.*" %>   
          <%! String str1,str2,str3,str4,str5,str6,str7,str8,str10,sid,tsid,date,month,year,day;
          int max;%>
        <% 

        try
        {

        str1=request.getParameter("fname");
        str2=request.getParameter("lname");
        str3=request.getParameter("faname");
        str5=request.getParameter("phno");
        str6=request.getParameter("email");
        str7=request.getParameter("gend");

        month=request.getParameter("DateOfBirth_Month");
        day=request.getParameter("DateOfBirth_Day");
        year=request.getParameter("DateOfBirth_Year");
        int str9=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("Department"));
        str10=request.getParameter("add");
        str8=day+"-"+month+"-"+year;

        //out.println(str1+"-"+str2+"-"+str3+"-"+str5+"-"+str6+"-"+str7+"-"+str8+"-"+str9+"-"+str10);
        if(str1.length()!=0&&str2.length()!=0&&str3.length()!=0
            &&str6.length()!=0&&str7.length()!=0&&str8.length()!=0&&str10.length()!=0)  
            {
            Statement st=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select max(id) from student");
            if(rs.next())
                sid=rs.getString(1);
            if(sid==null)
                sid="S100";
            tsid=sid.substring(1,sid.length());
            max=Integer.parseInt(tsid);
            max++;
            sid="S"+max;




            PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO student values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            pst.setString(1,sid);
            pst.setString(2,str1);
            pst.setString(3,str2);
            pst.setString(4,str3);
            pst.setString(5,str5);
            pst.setString(6,str6);
            pst.setString(7,str7);
            pst.setString(8,str8);
            pst.setInt(9,str9);
            pst.setString(10,str10);
            int k=pst.executeUpdate();

            %>
            <b><h2><center>Student Registration Successful...</center></h2></b>
            <h2> Student Id is  <% out.println(sid);%> </h2>
            <h3> Default Password is
            <% 
            String str="";
            for(int i=0;i<=8;i++)
            {
            str=str+(char)((int)'A'+Math.random()*((int)'Z'-(int)'A'+1));
            }
            out.println(str);
            PreparedStatement dst=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO LOGIN(USER_ID,PASSWORD,ROLE,COUNT) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
            dst.setString(1,sid);
            dst.setString(2,str);
            dst.setString(3,"STUDENT");
            dst.setInt(4,0);
            dst.executeUpdate();
            %>
            <br>
            <a href="adminhome.html">Back</a>
        <% pst.close();
            con.close(); }
            else
            {
            out.println("<b>Incomplete Student Information</b>");
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        out.println("Error:"+e);
        }%>

    </body>
</html>
```

**student registration form**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Student Registration</title>
    <script>
    window.history.forward();
    </script>

    <script>

            function validate()
            {
            formObj=document.f;
            for(var i=0;i<formObj.length;i++)
            {
            if(formObj.elements[i].value==""||formObj.elements[i].value=="Invalid")
            {
            alert("All fields must be completed with valid inormation for submission");
            formObj.elements[i].focus();
            return false;
            }
            }
       //Name
       var fname=document.f.Firstname;
       var nameexp=/[^a-zA-Z]$/;
     res=nameexp.test(fname.value);
     //alert(res);
       if(res)
       {
       alert("Enter Alphabets only for First Name");
       fname.select();
       return false;
       }

       var lname=document.f.Lastname;
       res=nameexp.test(lname.value);
       //alert(res);
       if(res)
       {
       alert("Enter Alphabets only for Last Name");
       lname.select();
       return false;
       }  

    //Address
                   var Address=document.f.Address.value;
                   var addxp=/[^a-zA-Z0-9]$/;
                  // alert(addxp.test(address));
                   if(addxp.test(address))
                   {
                   alert("check address");
                   return false;
                   }




               var mexp=/^(7|8|9)\d{9}$/;
               res=mexp.test(phoneno);
               if(!res)
               {
               alert("phoneno must start with 7,8 or 9");
               return false;
               }
                   //email ID
                   var emailid=document.f.emailid.value;
               var mailxp=/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
               if(!mailxp.test(emailid))
               {
               alert("check emailid");
               return false;
               }
                   }

    </script>                   







</head>
            <center><img border="0" src="Student Info Systems.jpg" alt="Pulpit rock" width="304" height="228" /></center><body  text="blue">
        <form action="stinsrt.jsp" method="post" name="f" onSubmit="return validate();">
        <center><h2>STUDENT REGISTRATION</h2>
        <pre>
        <table width="50%">
        <tr><td> Firstname:</td><td><input type="text" name="fname" size="15"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td> Lastname:</td><td><input type="text" name="lname" size="15"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td> Guardian/Parent Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="faname" size="15"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>D.O.B:</td><td><select name="DateOfBirth_Month">

<option> - Month - </option>

<option value="Jan">Jan</option>

<option value="Feb">Feb</option>

<option value="Mar">Mar</option>

<option value="Apr">Apr</option>

<option value="May">May</option>

<option value="Jun">Jun</option>

<option value="Jul">Jul</option>

<option value="Aug">Aug</option>

<option value="Sep">Sep</option>

<option value="Oct">Oct</option>

<option value="Nov">Nov</option>

<option value="Dec">Dec</option>

</select>

<select name="DateOfBirth_Day">

<option> - Day - </option>

<option value="1">1</option>

<option value="2">2</option>

<option value="3">3</option>

<option value="4">4</option>

<option value="5">5</option>

<option value="6">6</option>

<option value="7">7</option>

<option value="8">8</option>

<option value="9">9</option>

<option value="10">10</option>

<option value="11">11</option>

<option value="12">12</option>

<option value="13">13</option>

<option value="14">14</option>

<option value="15">15</option>

<option value="16">16</option>

<option value="17">17</option>

<option value="18">18</option>

<option value="19">19</option>

<option value="20">20</option>

<option value="21">21</option>

<option value="22">22</option>

<option value="23">23</option>

<option value="24">24</option>

<option value="25">25</option>

<option value="26">26</option>

<option value="27">27</option>

<option value="28">28</option>

<option value="29">29</option>

<option value="30">30</option>

<option value="31">31</option>

</select>



<select name="DateOfBirth_Year">

<option> - Year - </option>

<option value="04">2004</option>

<option value="03">2003</option>

<option value="02">2002</option>

<option value="01">2001</option>

<option value="00">2000</option>

<option value="99">1999</option>

<option value="98">1998</option>

<option value="97">1997</option>

<option value="96">1996</option>

<option value="95">1995</option>

<option value="94">1994</option>

<option value="93">1993</option>

<option value="92">1992</option>

<option value="91">1991</option>

<option value="90">1990</option>

<option value="89">1989</option>

<option value="88">1988</option>

<option value="87">1987</option>

<option value="86">1986</option>

<option value="84">1984</option>

<option value="83">1983</option>

<option value="82">1982</option>

<option value="81">1981</option>

<option value="80">1980</option>

<option value="79">1979</option>

<option value="78">1978</option>

<option value="77">1977</option>

<option value="76">1976</option>

<option value="75">1975</option>

<option value="74">1974</option>

<option value="73">1973</option>

<option value="72">1972</option>

<option value="71">1971</option>

<option value="70">1970</option>

<option value="69">1969</option>

<option value="68">1968</option>

<option value="67">1967</option>

<option value="66">1966</option>

<option value="65">1965</option>

<option value="64">1964</option>

<option value="63">1963</option>

<option value="62">1962</option>

<option value="61">1961</option>

<option value="60">1960</option>

<option value="59">1959</option>

<option value="58">1958</option>

<option value="57">1957</option>

<option value="56">1956</option>

<option value="55">1955</option>

<option value="54">1954</option>

<option value="53">1953</option>

<option value="52">1952</option>

<option value="51">1951</option>

<option value="50">1950</option>

<option value="49">1949</option>

<option value="48">1948</option>

<option value="47">1947</option>

<option value="46">1946</option>

<option value="45">1945</option>

<option value="44">1944</option>

<option value="43">1943</option>

<option value="42">1942</option>

<option value="41">1941</option>

<option value="40">1940</option>

<option value="39">1939</option>

<option value="38">1938</option>

<option value="37">1937</option>

<option value="36">1936</option>

<option value="35">1935</option>

<option value="34">1934</option>

<option value="33">1933</option>

<option value="32">1932</option>

<option value="31">1931</option>

<option value="30">1930</option>

<option value="29">1929</option>

<option value="28">1928</option>

<option value="27">1927</option>

<option value="26">1926</option>

<option value="25">1925</option>

<option value="24">1924</option>

<option value="23">1923</option>

<option value="22">1922</option>

<option value="21">1921</option>

<option value="20">1920</option>

<option value="19">1919</option>

<option value="18">1918</option>

<option value="17">1917</option>

<option value="16">1916</option>

<option value="15">1915</option>

<option value="14">1914</option>

<option value="13">1913</option>

<option value="12">1912</option>

<option value="11">1911</option>

<option value="10">1910</option>

<option value="09">1909</option>

<option value="08">1908</option>

<option value="07">1907</option>

<option value="06">1906</option>

<option value="05">1905</option>

<option value="04">1904</option>

<option value="03">1903</option>

<option value="02">1902</option>

<option value="01">1901</option>

<option value="00">1900</option>

</select></td></tr></tr>
        <tr><td>Gender:</td><td><input type="radio" name="gend" value="male"/>Male  <input type="radio" name="gend" value="female"/>Female</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Phone no:</td><td><input type="text" name="phno" size="15"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>email ID:</td><td><input type="text" name="email" size="15"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Department:</td><td><select name="Department" >
                            <option value="1">CSE</option>
                            <option value="2">ECE</option>
                            <option value="3">EEE</option>
                            <option value="4">MECH</option>
                            <option value="5">MBA</option>
                            </select></td></tr></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Address:</td><td><textarea name="add" rows="4" cols="20"  ></textarea></td></tr>



        <tr><td><input type="submit" name="sub" value="submit">
        <input type="button" name="cancel" value="Cancel" onclick="window.location.replace('adminhome.html')"></td></t>
        </table>
        </pre>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

pls help me . 
Thank you.

Comment: The Post-Redirect-Get pattern is what you need.

Comment: This is an awful lot of code for someone to look through to give you an answer.  Check out http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for some ideas on how to restate your question in a way that will make people more willing to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the data from the form object fields "after" you have inserted it by looping over it.
If the user needs to know what they inserted in the returned page, write it in with HTML ordinary text elements not the form or at least remove the form request url from the form tag.